# Is there a good API for blacklisted domains?

Tags: api, spam-prevention, email-spam

just curious if there was a good service paid or unpaid where I can send in either a user's email address or the domain from their email address and get back if they're a known spammer or not?

thanks

Comment: As described in your question, this doesn't sound very useful. Spammers almost never use their own email addresses. Most spam is from either stolen/spoofed addresses or throw-away accounts (Yahoo Mail or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Spammers usually forge their email address (sometimes using the email addresses of legitimate users like yourself). They don't need to know your password, they just pretend like they're sending it on your behalf. The same thing applies to domains. Using either one for detecing spam is likely to be inaccurate.

The email headers (your email software should provide some way to see it) should actually provide IP information about where the email originated from. The IP address is one of the few ways to check for spam. First you can check it using something like [MX Toolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) to check several blacklists, (including spamhaus)

Other methods for identifying spam include DKIM and SPF. Usually your email provider should automatically check these and rate the spam if they fail either SKIM or SPF.

Answer (score 0):

As Chuck said it will not be a useful method to prevent e-mail spams. There are some other techniques looking the content and discretes if an e-mail is a spam or not using tokenizer methods. i suggest you to glance at [SpamBayes](http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Comment: I'm just looking to find out if an email address is coming from a known spam domain, I won't have a msg to attach it to

Comment: Spammers generally fake where the e-mail is coming from.